How Do I Resolve "Column name is ambiguous" Error in BigQuery with dbt Incremental Model?
I am trying to build an incremental model for Facebook advertising data and am receiving this error saying:
  Column name Campaign_ID is ambiguous at [94:42]

This is my code
{{ config(materialized='incremental', unique_key='date,Campaign_ID,Ad_Group_ID,Ad_ID') }}

with facebook_data as (
    select
        '{{ invocation_id }}' as batch_id,  
        date as Date,
        'Meta' as Platform,
        account as Account,
        account_id as Account_ID,
        campaign_id as Campaign_ID,
        adset_id as Ad_Group_ID,
        ad_id as Ad_ID
    from
        {{ source('source_facebookads', 'raw_facebookads_ads') }}
    where 
        date > DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL -7 DAY)
    group by
        date,
        publisher_platform,
        account,
        account_id,
        campaign_id,
        adset_id,
        ad_id
)

select * from facebook_data

{% if is_incremental() %}
where date >= (select max(date) from {{ this }})
{% endif %}


If I run this in 'Preview' within the DBT Cloud IDE, it works. But, when I run "dbt run" it fails saying that I have an ambigious column 'Campaign_ID'.
I've tried specifying the table associated with Campaign ID in the SQL and in my config block, but that didn't work.
What do I do here?

Not sure if that's the issue, but the only error that I find in your code is with how you declare the unique_key: according to the docs, when passing more than one column you should define that variable as a list (or array).
So, instead of:
{{ config(materialized='incremental', unique_key='date,Campaign_ID,Ad_Group_ID,Ad_ID') }}
I'd try with:
{{
  config(
    materialized='incremental',
    unique_key=['date', 'Campaign_ID', 'Ad_Group_ID', 'Ad_ID']
  ) 
}}

